# ruby ocra wont compile scripts with business_time gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ocra

Trying to compile a ruby script to a Windows executable using ocra.  For some reason since adding business_time to the script, it refuses to compile.  If I remove the require 'business_time'  it will compile.  So I created a script for just business_time and it works but will not compile.  Struggling to see what the issue is from the ERROR message.

Thanks in advance.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'business_time'

puts 1.business_day.ago.strftime("%Y%m%d") 
puts 1.business_day.ago.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ocra-1.3.0/bin/ocra:467: Use
>   RbConfig instead o
>       f obsolete and deprecated Config.
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/tests/basics.rb:8:in
>   `test'
>       : unknown command 'a' (ArgumentError)
>               from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/tests/basics.r
>       b:8:in`'
>               from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/tests/basics.r
>       b:3:in `<module:Tests>'
>               from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/tests/basics.r
>       b:2:in`'
>               from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/tests/basics.r
>       b:1:in `<top (required)>'
>               from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ocra-1.3.0/bin/ocra:467:in`const_
>       get'
>               from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ocra-1.3.0/bin/ocra:467:in `block
>       (3 levels) in attempt_load_autoload'
>               from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ocra-1.3.0/bin/ocra:464:in`each'
>               from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ocra-1.3.0/bin/ocra:464:in `block
>       (2 levels) in attempt_load_autoload'
>               from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ocra-1.3.0/bin/ocra:462:in`each'
>               from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ocra-1.3.0/bin/ocra:462:in `block
>       in attempt_load_autoload'
>               from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ocra-1.3.0/bin/ocra:456:in`loop'
>               from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ocra-1.3.0/bin/ocra:456:in `attemp
>       t_load_autoload'
>               from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ocra-1.3.0/bin/ocra:679:in`build_
>       exe'
>               from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ocra-1.3.0/bin/ocra:1138:in `block
>        in '
>
> ```
> C:\Ruby>
> ```